# add custom event on calender in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add note on calendar. Note is created in `AddContact.m` controller and calendar view created  on another controller (`CelenderView.m`).

How I show created note on calendar view. I want to match both date and display dot on that date.

Comment: do you want to add it in device calendar ?

Comment: No,I create calenderview  into seprate controller as a celenderController.h .Using JTCalender classe